# Vbulletin Editor BBcodes JS Click event

Tags: javascript, alert, bbcode, vbulletin

I want to pop up an alert when a user clicks on a BBcode icon in editor.
for example, I have a Spoiler BBcode and I want the event below for it :

```
onClick=alert("// Something Here")>
```

Where should I add this event ?! where are the codes for a BBcode which exists in editor ?

More explanation about the thing I need:
I have a Spoiler which makes  tag.
I want to add an option for it like .
"sth" is the string which users insert in a text input which has been alerted after they click on the BBcode icon in Editor. Then, the content will hide or show by clicking on "Sth"

This is my Spoiler code :

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; font-size: 1em;">
<div style="text-transform: uppercase;text-decoration:underline; font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; display: block;">

<span onClick=" if (this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') {
this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = ''; this.innerHTML = '<a href=\'#\' onClick=\'return false;\'>Hide</a>'; }
else { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.innerHTML = '<a href=\'#\' onClick=\'return false;\'>Show</a>'; }" />

<a href="#" onClick="return false;">Show</a></span></div><div class="quotecontent">
<div style="display: none;">{param}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this :

/clientscript/ckeplugins/bbcode/plugin.js

The Editor in VB vary widely from the original standalone one.

thus , it seems hard to work with it.